# can't boot, get message: ... terminated with status 127

Tags: boot

boot fails with the following message:

```
/etc/default/locale: 5: d_fmt: not found
init: mountall main process (234) terminated with status 127
```

if I boot to Recovery, is there any way to edit this locale file or to delete it and replace it with a default one? How can I edit the Locale file to fix this problem without being able to boot?

Answer (score 2):

Boot into the Recovery mode, and if that doesn't work, into a LiveCD. Then edit the file, there should be something like

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

(depending on your locale). Use `sudo nano /etc/default/locale` in Recovery or `gksudo /media/ubuntu/etc/default/locale` in the LiveCD (change */media/ubuntu/* appropriately depending on where you mounted the Ubuntu partition).